# Implement Autocomplete Intellisense when creating NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to create my own `NPM` package. In which I want to implement Autocomplete Intellisense when any user is using my NPM package.

Here is very basic NPM package.

**Models.js**

```
class Model {
static schema(fields) {
    return new Manager(fields);
}
}

class Manager {
constructor(fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}

save() {
    console.log(this.fields);
    console.log("save these fields");
}
}

export default Model;
```

**main.js** (When user is using my NPM package)

```
import Model from "./models.js";

const userModel = Model.schema({
name: "string",
age: "number",
});

const user = userModel;
```

I want whenever someone type **user.** it will show **user.name and user.age** currently it only
show **user.fields and user.save**.

[image]

It showing only those properties and methods which are predefined not those which user defined later. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: *"intenseness"* - Intellisense? You have to provide additional type information, e.g. use typescript and distribute the .d.ts files alongside the .js.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an interface for the user to be able to see those things you need
to work with [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/)
You use it to create an interface that the user will know what he can get from and object/function/class etc...

Comment: But problem is that these are not static one these are dynamic vary from user to user which properties they mention how can I defined these in `JSDoc` simply how can I define show those properties which are under `field` object ?